# Comma separated against unique value via vba

Tags: vba, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phErT.png)How u are doing well, i want to required data by vba programing. can you guys help me.

below is raw data.

USERID  QTY Loc
14405   18  India
34479   18  UK
38155   14  India
35365   19  UK
47669   17  Nepal
51680   18  Jermani
16124   14  china
51915   20  India
14405   11  UK
34479   14  India
38155   14  UK
35365   14  Nepal
47669   12  Jermani
51680   13  china
16124   16  India
51915   10  UK
14405   16  India
34479   17  UK
38155   20  Nepal

Below is Required format

USERID  Loc QTY
14405   India,UK    45
16124   china,India 30
34479   India,UK    49
35365   Nepal,UK    33
38155   India,Nepal,UK  48
47669   Jermani,Nepal   29
51680   china,Jermani   31
51915   India,UK    30

Comment: Where does 45 16124 come from?  It's not in the original example??

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, something that will start you with some standard excel functionality.

1. Paste your data in a single cell, and split using Text to columns on DATA tab:

[image: First]

2. Split the data as space delimited:

[image: Second]

3. Copy all data and paste special as transposed to get in single column form:

[image: Third]

4. Tidy up, Delete the top row. Then use this formula `=IF(MOD(ROW();3)=1;OFFSET($A1;COLUMN()-3;0);"del")` e.g. in C1 and extend it to next two columns so you have three total.

[image: Fourth]

5. Drag down to match your data:

[image: Fifth]

6. Copy all that data into another area as values (right click or paste special):

[image: Sixth]

7. Move the columns the way you want it and when done do the ctrl+f type del as searched phrase and in result box under find select one of results and do ctrl+a. This will highlight all matching cells and you can right click delete all of them in one go.

[image: Seventh]

8. Done

[image: Done]

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your string in A1 cell.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Long
    i = 2
    For k = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        For j = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(1, k).Value
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```